# NodeJS Sequelize Query: Is WHERE data between columns is possible?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Basically, i want to query like this one on sequelize without using raw query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE 10000 BETWEEN "minAmount" AND "maxAmount"
AND 30 BETWEEN "minDay" AND "maxDay"
```

is this possible? I can't find solutions there, perhaps you can help me about this.

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `BETWEEN` with a pair of `>=` and `<=` and that does the trick:

```js
const rows = await TableNameModel.findAll({
where: {
  minAmount: {
    [Op.lte]: 10000
  },
  maxAmount: {
    [Op.gte]: 10000
  },
  minDay: {
    [Op.lte]: 30
  },
  maxDay: {
    [Op.gte]: 30
  },
}
});
```